# Polymorph and equipment. How does it work?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, equipment, polymorph

What does happen when you polymorph into a creature that has a specific-weapon and uses it to attack? I am not referring to natural weapons.

As Alter Self says:

> You acquire the physical qualities of the new form while retaining your own mind. Physical qualities include natural size, mundane movement capabilities, natural armor bonus, natural weapons, racial skill bonuses, racial bonus feats, and any gross physical qualities .
>
> [...]
>
> When the change occurs, your equipment, if any, either remains worn or held by the new form (if it is capable of wearing or holding the item), or melds into the new form and becomes nonfunctional. When you revert to your true form, any objects previously melded into the new form reappear in the same location on your body they previously occupied and are once again functional.

So, from what I can read nothing refers to the equipment the new form could have. If I polymorph into a devil that uses a sword will I get that weapon during the time the spell is active? No, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not get equipment always carried by the creature. As you pointed out in the question, polymorph is explicit about what it grants, and equipment is not included. In fact, the only interaction polymorph has with equipment is to absorb it for the duration if the caster is using equipment that the new form is incapable of using, too.